# Error while trying to impute missing values using Panda's 'loc' functionin Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to impute missing values in one of the columns in my dataset using the *'loc'* function of Panda library but the code is not executing successfully. The line of code is as below.

```
# Impute missing data by mean weight of each sub-category in 'Item_Weight' column

data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Weight'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight[x])
```

The error that is being generated is as follows,

```
data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Weight'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight[x])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-168be6231060>", line 1, in <module>
    data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Weight'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight[x])

  File "C:\Users\Arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3192, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File "<ipython-input-3-168be6231060>", line 1, in <lambda>
    data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Weight'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight[x])

  File "C:\Users\Arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2685, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\Arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2692, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\Arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2486, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Users\Arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Users\Arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3065, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'FDP10'
```

I observed that the last line of the error trace says *'KeyError : 'FDP10'*.

**FDP10** is precisely the first value from the *'Item_Identifier'* column for which the corresponding cell in the *'Item_Weight'* column is blank (aka has a missing value).

So, appears that the first blank column this code hits, it fails to replace that blank column with the replacement value.

An alternative code I found is,

```
data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Weight'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight.at[x,'Item_Weight'])
```

The logic behind this alternative code also appears sound to me. But my question is what is wrong with the original code ?

Let me know if you need any additional info, I will provide the same!

Comment: Did you check the content of your miss_bool array? Because it might be containing that 'FDP10' value

Comment: @m33n the miss_bool array (I should rather say vector since it has only one column) contains true-false data. For each entry in the original dataset file 'data', if a record row has a missing value in its 'Item_Weight' column then in miss_bool vector, the row corresponding to that index has a 'true' value, else 'false'. I hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

While analysis, found out that 4 products in train dataset had one row with missing value, so a probable solution would be to refer test data set which contains item weight of 4 missing products.

Answer (score 0):

this has gotta do with the use of pivot_table

Go for :

`item_avg_weight = df.groupby('Item_Identifier').mean()['Item_Weight']`

Instead of :

```
item_avg_weight = df.pivot_table(values='Item_Weight', index='Item_Identifier')
```

So,that u would not have to use the at function and then simply write:

```
df.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Weight'] = df.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight[x])
```